# UDP in C# works on Windows but not Linux

Tags: c#, windows, ubuntu, mono, fedora

I'm using mono to build a C# program that needs to send and receive using UDP. Currently my implementation works as expected on Windows but I have issues getting communication to work with my Ubuntu or Fedora systems.

Windows can broadcast and receive it's own datagrams. 
Ubuntu can broadcast and receive it's own datagrams. It's broadcasts are received by Windows but *it doesn't see datagrams broadcast by Windows.* 
Fedora can broadcast but does not receive datagrams from anywhere (not even itself). It's broadcasts are received by Windows.

When datagrams fail to reach either of the linux machines, the 'receive' function is never fired.

This is what I have so far:

```
int _port = 4568;
var server = new UdpClient(_port);
var send_UDP = new UdpClient();
```

The receive method uses the asynchronous calls of the UDPClient;

```
private static void receive()
{
    server.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(receive), null);
}
private static void receive(IAsyncResult o)
{           
    try
    {
        // I'm told that port = 0 should receive from any port.
        var sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        var data = server.EndReceive(o, ref sender);
        receive();
        var str = new string(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(data));
        postmessage(sender.Address.ToString() + ":" + sender.Port.ToString() + " > " + str);
    }
    catch {}
}
```

And the send method;

```
public static void send(string message)
{
    var target = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255"), _port);
    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
    send_UDP.Send(data, data.Length, target);
}
```

After some testing with Fedora, it seems to be an issue with the use of 255.255.255.255 to broadcast. Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you tried removing the `try-catch` to see if there is any runtime errors? Have you set a breakpoint in `receive` to see if it gets called at all?

Comment: The 'try-catch' is only for receiving from multiple users - in my debug code the exception is printed to the console.
I'll try debugging the receive method on the other systems (it wasn't something I had thought to try).

Comment: The receive code is never fired on Fedora. This seems to be regardless of where the datagram originated (I tried sending from the local machine and from a windows box).

Comment: Do you have any firewall rules that are preventing the packets from moving around freely? Have you confirmed with something like Wireshark that the packets are actually being sent or received?

Comment: Each packet is received by the Windows machine so they are definitely being sent.
I wasn't able to get Wireshark to work on Linux but I used bash's UDP broadcast function to broadcast a packet to the loopback address - it was received fine by my application. However the issue seems to be with my use of 255.255.255.255 to broadcast to every IP on the local network.

Comment: Since you haven't specified, I take it you are doing this across a LAN - use your local  IP subnet (for instance 192.168.60.255 instead of 255.255.255.255).

Comment: Broadcasting to the loopback device on the same machine doesn't really help you at all.  You need to make sure that the packets from the Windows machine actually arrive on your Linux box.  Use something like `tcpdump -i eth0 -vv udp` on the command-line.  Have you checked your firewall settings?  A common default setup for many Linux distros is not to allow any incoming udp traffic.

Comment: Have you tried: var target = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, _port);

Comment: For starters, just turn off the firewall altogether, just to see if it starts working, and isolate the issue. I doubt this is a code problem.

Comment: Can you try running 2 machines with Windows in same network? If one Windows machine can see the broadcasts from the other Windows one, the problem is definitely in firewall, if it can't - the problem is in your code that sends broadcasts (unlikely, though).

Comment: This is definately not a bug in Mono... we use the same UDP code (c#) on Linux, Windows, MacOS, etc... So like the others suggested you need to check the network setup, firewall rules, etc

Comment: Seems it's a network problem rather than a programming problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone. I'm waiting to get that information from the clients machine and to see how it compares to the test/dev machines I've been using.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Wireshark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already specified this in a comment but placing this as an answer since you may have overlooked it and no answers seem to be forthcoming.

Instead of using `255.255.255.255` for broadcast use your local IP subnet's broadcasting address (for instance 192.168.0.255 on a 192.168.0.1/24 subnet). The `255.255.255.255`address will not be forwarded by a router (this is relevant if there are multiple subnets at your clients' sites) whereas a directed broadcast can be forwarded (if so configured). It used to be the case that routers would forward directed broadcasts per default but this was changed in [RFC2644](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2644) so don't bet the farm on it ;).

Here's an example of calculating the directed IPV4 broadcast address per adapter:

```
public static void DisplayDirectedBroadcastAddresses()
{

    foreach (var iface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
             .Where(c => c.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(iface.Description);
        foreach (var ucastInfo in iface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
                 .Where(c => !c.Address.IsIPv6LinkLocal))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tIP       : {0}", ucastInfo.Address);
            Console.WriteLine("\tSubnet   : {0}", ucastInfo.IPv4Mask);
            byte[] ipAdressBytes = ucastInfo.Address.GetAddressBytes();
            byte[] subnetMaskBytes = ucastInfo.IPv4Mask.GetAddressBytes();

            if (ipAdressBytes.Length != subnetMaskBytes.Length) continue;
                
            var broadcast = new byte[ipAdressBytes.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < broadcast.Length; i++)
            {
                broadcast[i] = (byte)(ipAdressBytes[i] | ~(subnetMaskBytes[i]));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\tBroadcast: {0}", new IPAddress(broadcast).ToString());
        }
    }
            
}
```